# How to implement shortcut keys in Django using jquery?

Tags: python, django

I have been working for a accounting based project using `Django-2.0.6` and `python-3.6`.

I want to implement shortcut keys in my project using jquery.

I have tried a library known as `django-keyboard-shortcuts` but it doesnot supports python3.

So I want to do it using jquery or any other option(if is there).

For example:

If I press Cntrl + R or any other combination from my keyboard it will redirect me to the desired url given in the combination.

**Update**

I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keypress(function(event) {
                if (event.which === 99) { window.location = '{% url 'accounting_double_entry:groupcreate' pk=company_details.pk pk3=selectdatefield_details.pk %}'; }
            });

        });
```

But got one problem that when I try to put combination of keys like `ctrl+q` or something like that it does not works.

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you